# Changing Legend Arrangement/Style in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, style, legend

In ArcMap 10.3 you were able to change the vertical/horizontal arrangement of patch, label, description in the legend via the Style button on the Legend Properties Items tab.  I cannot locate something similar in ArcGIS Pro.  It looks like you can change the order horizontally but I want to put the label above the patch.  I have messed around with the offets and can move the labels around a bit but cannot adjust the patch location.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question to yours has been asked at GeoNet as [What happened to legend styles in Pro?](https://community.esri.com/thread/228730-what-happened-to-legend-styles-in-proThere)

There does not seem to be anything in ArcGIS Pro 2.4 akin to the Legend Styles of ArcMap.

Consequently, if the options in ArcGIS Pro to [Work with a legend](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/work-with-a-legend.htm) do not meet your requirements I recommend that to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).  I looked for and could not find an existing one.